# SQL - Get MIN of a column for each key in other table

Tags: sql, apache-spark, join

I have two tables as such:

ORDERS

| Date | TransactID | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06 | **1234** | 4 |
| 2021-09 | **1238** | 8 |

Agg

| Date | User | TransactID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06 | 3333 | **1234** |
| 2021-03 | 3333 | XXXX |
| **2021-02** | 3333 | XXXX |
| 2021-09 | 4444 | **1238** |
| 2021-05 | 4444 | XXXX |
| **2021-01** | 4444 | XXXX |

In AGG, a User can have many transactions, the ORDERS table is just a subset of it.

For each TransactID in Orders, I need to go into the Agg table and get the **MIN** date for the User associated with the TransactID.

Then, I need to calculate the date difference between the ORDERS.Date and the minimum AGG.DATE. The result is stored in SDP.COL3. COL3 can basically be described as **Days Since First Transaction**.

I have never done a SQL problem that is this multistep, and need some guidance. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what have you tried and what was the result?  also can you create a sql fiddle so that we can reproduce this with minimal effort to help you

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/101497/1
@SimonPrice
I am VERY new to SQL, and am trying to think in normal Python etc where I can for loop over each row.
Basically, I need to return two results, the min date for EACH user in the AGG table.

Comment: ok, so in your fiddle the tables is no relational data, there is no primary and foreign key constraints. Is this how your actual data is set up too?

Comment: @SimonPrice I am just recreating the tables minimally here. There are no primary/foreign constraints as this is from Spark SQL. Hope that helps. I know, it is frustrating that there is no direct key relation for what I am doing.

Comment: additionally, you are massively duplicating data in your tables

Comment: Yup, 100%. The small table is a subset of the larger one, but omitting the User ID column.

Comment: If my answer doesnt give you what you need, can you provide a fuller fiddle so that this can be better achieved for you.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also _specify_ the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've got it right

```
SELECT SDP.TXN_ID, sdp.dt, datediff(sdp.dt, min(a1.DT)) diff
FROM SDP
JOIN AGG a1 on a1.UserID =
  (SELECT a2.UserID 
   FROM AGG a2 
   WHERE SDP.TXN_ID = a2.TXN_ID
   ORDER BY a2.UserID
   limit 1)
GROUP BY SDP.TXN_ID, sdp.dt
```

You can omit

```
   ORDER BY a2.UserID
   limit 1
```

provided each transaction is always belonging to a single user.

[The fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/101497/8)

Answer (score 0):

based on your SQL Fidddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/101497/1) this should get you started

```
SELECT TXN_ID, DT, USERID
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sdp.TXN_ID ORDER BY  sdp.DT ASC) AS [index],
             sdp.TXN_ID,
             sdp.DT,
             agg.USERID 
      FROM sdp
      LEFT JOIN agg ON sdp.TXN_ID = agg.TXN_ID) A
WHERE [index] = 1
```

For more information you should look at

https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-partition-by-clause-overview/

https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-window-functions/sql-partition-by/

https://learnsql.com/blog/partition-by-with-over-sql/